# VBA Excel: How to delete filtered rows exclude heading

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$V$").Offset(1, 17).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$17:$V$110").AutoFilter Field:=4
```

It seems there is an error.  Does anyone know what's the problem with this code?

The fact:
I have written code to filter the wording that would like to delete to visible.
So, second step is I would like to delete those filtered rows that are visible.
Then after that clear all filter to present everything.

Answer (score 2):

`"$A$1:$V$"` is not a valid Excel address.  Based on your second line, I suggest you wanted

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$V$110").Offset(1, 17).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```